# Difference between k8s principals on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

I'm new to Azure and k8s and somewhat confused about when to assign rights to which principal.

Whats the difference between assigning rights to `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.[name].kubelet_identity[0].object_id` vs `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.[name].identity.0.principal_id` and are there any other principals on the cluster that might be relevant in some other situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.[name].kubelet_identity[0].object_id` = Managed identity of your user node pool ( this identity is needed for example to access the ACR in order to pull images or acces the AKV via CSI integration )

`azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.[name].identity.0.principal_id` = Managed identity of your AKS ( this identity is needed for example to add new nodes to the Vnet or use Monitoring/Metrics )